# Set environment variables in AWS EMR during bootstrap

Tags: bash, amazon-emr

I added the following configuration in `spark-env`

```
--configurations '[
     {
       "Classification": "spark-env",
       "Properties": {},
       "Configurations": [
           {
             "Classification": "export",
             "Properties": {
                 "MY_VARIABLE": "MY_VARIABLE"
             }
           }
       ]
     }
     ]'
```

But if I just do `echo $MY_VARIABLE` in bash I can't see them in the terminal.

Basically what I want to do is the following:

- schedule the creation of an AWS EMR cluster with AWS Lambda (where I would set all my environment variables such as git credentials)
- in the bootstrapping of the machine, install a bunch of things, including git
- git clone a repository (so I need to use the credentials stored in the environment variables)
- execute some code from this repository

Comment: The question is not a duplicate @tripleee. For clarity, I have edited the question. The linked duplicate question is specifically for env variables for spark application, these variables are not present during EMR bootstrapping.

Comment: you can make use of `Tags`

Comment: @Vishrant Thanks for the feedback; reopened.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the environment variables as arguments to the bootstrap action.

Comment: when we try to get credentials securely, passing them through the command line or in an s3 file breaks the requirements

Comment: I think it's not safe as well to put those things as ENV vars, anyway, you should put it in parameter store, and only pass the parameter name over to the script in as a script argument.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you can't find `MY_VARIABLE` using `echo` is because `MY_VARIABLE` is only available to the spark-env.

Assuming you are using pyspark, if you open a pyspark shell (whilst you are ssh'd into one of the nodes of your cluster) and you try to type `os.getenv("MY_VARIABLE")` you'll see the value of you assigned to that variable.

An alternative solution for your use case would be: instead of using credentials (which in general is not the preferred way), you could use a set of keys that allows you to clone a repo with SSH (rather than https). You can store those keys in aws ssm and retrieve those in the EMR bootstrap script. An example could be:

**bootstrap.sh**

```
export SSM_VALUE=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name $REDSHIFT_DWH_PUBLIC_KEY --with-decryption --query 'Parameter.Value' --output text)
echo $SSM_VALUE >> $AUTHORIZED_KEYS
```

In my case, I needed to connect to a Redshift instance, but this would work nicely also with your use case.

Alessio

Comment: I'm not sure how is this different, environement variables set up during bootstrap are not accessible